# Image hosting with Dropbox in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dropbox

Hi I'm trying to use Dropbox as an imaging hosting server. The framework is currently Ruby.

I tried to use /media or /shares to get the data's url. When I use "/media" command, it seems the image can be hosted for a couple of hours but at the end it expires(4? hours roughly). If possible, I want to know how to set the expiration dates for this ( at something like 1 year? ), not manually, but in a programmable manner.

[How I extract "url" in Ruby]

```
image_1_link = Drop_client.media('path_name')["url"]
pdf_link = Drop_client.shares(''path_name'["url"]
```

The below is a sample link after using "/media".
     "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/e9lr642qerdmgm9/Apps/ringle_records/images/Test_1image_1?dl=1"

When I use "/share", the generated link looks like "https://db.tt/Zs0v4yaffal?dl=1". But it can't host the image if I use it as . If I put this type of address, it leads to dropbox page and ask manual downloading.

I want to know how to generate link for imaging hosting so that  can work for 1 year or at least for a couple of months!

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/media` links expire after 4 hours, [as documented](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#media).

`/shares` takes a parameter, `short_url`, that can be set to `false` to return an unshortened URL. Unfortunately, I believe the v1 Ruby SDK doesn't support this parameter. You can either modify the Ruby SDK yourself or get the shortened URL and unshorten it yourself. (Make an HTTP GET request to the short URL and grab the `Location` header of the redirect response.)

Once you have an unshortened URL, you can modify it per [www.dropbox.com/help/201](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201) to get a link directly to the content. Specifically, you should use the `raw=1` query parameter.

Comment: I found in other stackoverflow posting about this issue. As it said, I made a customized version for generating un-shortened link. >>> client = DropboxClient.new(access_token)
    session = DropboxOAuth2Session.new(access_token, nil)
    response = session.do_get "/shares/auto/#{client.format_path(path)}", {"short_url"=>false}
    Dropbox::parse_response(response)